# How can I write an assert function to assert a discriminated union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a discriminated union:

```js
type State =
    { tag: "A", /* other props */ }
  | { tag: "B", /* other props */ }
```

Now I have a piece of code that can only work in a certain state:

```js
// Somewhere
const state: State = …;

// And later elsewhere
if (state.tag !== "A") {
  throw new AssertionError(…);
}

// Here I am sure `state` is of type A
```

Can I rewrite the condition into an assert function?

```js
// Somewhere
const assertState = (state: State, tag: State["tag"]) => ???

// And later:
assertState(state, "A");

// Here I am sure `state` is of type A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```
type State =
    { tag: "A", /* other props */ }
  | { tag: "B", /* other props */ }

function assertState (condition: boolean): asserts condition { 
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error("message")
  }
}

function test(){
  let state: State = {} as any

  assertState(state.tag === 'A')

  state.tag // is only of type `A` now
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=34&pln=5&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4BQUNQN5QQcwC4oAiAQWIBooB6AKigHtgALCAJyjDYbAGcpa1KAF90UAD7Zc8QiQBClGvSasOXHv0EjUqAGYBXAHYBjYAEsGhqPF692wOImgAKY5YAmZ85aIAjBgwANhDwhgCURDZ2bMD8boae3lY4Yma6UM4AhPGJFuHYYhgs3ADuUIYQZQCibNxszsQAthC2MhDEYWKionpGpnm4LcDOYVhiwcBQvAhIRI5IUMjYwtb8oSA6GFH28xDO004AdPiLyEsA5KTnnWIHSMcyqMJAA)